# If I use the same class name in different styles in multiple Less files, will they affect each other?

Tags: css, less

if I use the same class name in multiple less files and define different styles, will it be a problem while building with css?

For example, under the same class name

```
.test {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
}
```

to file1 and

```
.test {
   display: flex;
   align-items: flex-start;
}
```

to file 2.

I'm posting because I found such a problem now.
The changes in file 1 are affecting the ui in file 2.
And vice versa.

Comment: If those rules are used for the same HTML page which has at least one element with that class, then yes. That's how CSS works at its very core.